# Problema al intentar mostrar un loader mientras realizo busqueda

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Tengo un problema, tengo un componente que muestra resultados de busqueda. La idea es que si la busqueda se está realizando, mostrar un `loader`. Una vez que termina, se muestran los resultados o un mensaje de error.

El problema es que, si bien todo parece funcionar correctamente, hay un pequeño intervalo de tiempo en el que `loading` pasa a ser `false`, el `loader` desaparece, y justo antes de mostrar los resultados se muestra el mensaje de error diciendo que no hay resultados.

Este error, como digo, dura un pequeño intervalo de tiempo, y luego se muestran correctamente los resultados. Pero la idea es que no suceda.

Tengo un hook `useSearch` que tiene, entre muchas cosas, esto:

```
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);

 const fetchSearchResults = async location => {
    // This function calls /api to retrieve search results based on filters and router url
    setLoading(true);

    // Grab the query parameters or filters for call to api
    ...
    const dataURL = API_URL

    const results = await (await fetch(dataURL)).json();

    if (results.statusCode === 404) {
      return router.push("/404");
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
      setAllResults(results.data?.results);
      await handleChangeLocation(false);
    }
  };
```

Mi componente donde se muestran los resultados esta contenido en un componente padre (una pagina). En este se llama a `useSearch` y se le pasan ciertos valores por props al componente de resultados:

```
    <SearchResults
      allResults={allResults}
      filteredResults={filteredResults}
      loading={loading}
      ...
    />
```

Finalmente, en `SearchResults`, tengo esta funcion para renderizar los datos:

```
const Results = useMemo(() => {
    if (loading) {
      return (
        <div className="loading">
          <DynamicFontAwesomeIcon
            className="fa-pulse"
            color="#26707b"
            icon={faSpinner}
            size="2xl"
          />
        </div>
      );
    }

    if (filteredResults?.length > 0) {
      return filteredResults.map((resort, index) => (
        <SearchResultCard
          className={filteredResults.length === 1 ? "one-result" : ""}
          handleCondosModal={() => handleCondosModal(resort.id)}
          index={index}
          isSearchPage={isSearchPage}
          key={`resort-${resort?.id || index}`}
          resort={resort}
          setSelectedMapIndex={setSelectedMapIndex}
        />
      ));
    }

    return <EmptyList text={emptyMessage || "No condo units found based on your search filters. Please try your search again or choose a different filter."} />;
  }, [
    loading,
    filteredResults,
    showPrice,
  ]);
```

> Evidentemente hay un pequeño lapso en el cual `loader` pasa a ser false pero todavia no se pasan los `filteredResults` y por esto es que muestra el mensaje como si no hubiera resultados. Alguien ve el error, o necesito subir mas codigo?

Comment: Por el momento lo até con alambre. Primero, setee el estado inicial del loader en ``true`` en lugar de ``null``, porque el mensaje de error tambien se mostraba un instante al momento de cargarse la pagina. Finalmente, agregue un setTimeout de 500ms al momento de hacer ``setLoader(false)`` y se ve bien. Si aparece una respuesta mejor estaria agradecido.

Comment: A mi lo que se me ocurre de primeras, igual te vale es cambiar de linea el setLoading por el setAllresults. Ya que tu problema es que hay un pequeño momento en el que no esta cargando y no tienes resultados. igual así te vale

Comment: Lo probe pero sin suerte. Incluso le puse un await al setAllresults

Comment: Creo que el problema están en donde seteas filteredResults. Porque cuando llamas a la api no veo que setees esa variable, por eso tienes ese tiempo sin datos. No se si lo haces en otro componente, si es así podrías pasarle a ese mismo componente la funcion que setea loading para que despues de modificar filteredresults, modifiques loading, así no te pasaría eso